# Dont know, why the my app url is ashowing as undefined, inside include function of project url

Tags: django, django-views, django-apps

[File structure of my project and app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmDZg.png)
Django

All the steps needed to make a virtual environment. Then make a project,and an app, then write a view function inside the app level. Then map it with urls inside the app.
Finally when going to project,s url.py and map the app's URL with include function. It is not working. (Showing as undefined).

I am really stuck in it for two days. If someone could help me, it would be very good,

Comment: use it as string value `include("myapp.urls")`